# "I’d like to have the voice of Jim Morrison's." or "I’d like to have the voice of Jim Morrison"?

Tags: single-word-requests, grammar

> I’d like to have the voice of Jim Morrison's.

Or,

> I’d like to have the voice of Jim Morrison.

**Which one is correct?**

Comment: There is an interesting twist here that is relevant but you would have to give us your thoughts/research on this for this to be a legitimate question here.

Comment: You probably mean you'd like to *sing like* J. Morrison

Comment: @Mari-LouA I'd like to have Jim Morrison's voice. Colloquially, of course, and which, of course, means what you just wrote.

Answer (score 1):

"I'd like to have the voice of Jim Morrison" is correct. The alternative here is not.

The apostrophe, in this case, shows possession of something. You could say "I'd like to have Jim Morrison's voice" - and that would be correct. It is saying you would like the voice possessed by Jim Morrison.

When you say "I'd like to have the voice of Jim Morrison's", it sounds like the sentence is not complete: you'd like the voice of Jim Morrison's what? The voice of Jim Morrison's voice? That does not make sense.

However you could say "I'd like to have the voice of Jim Morrison's cat" - and that would be grammatically correct.

Comment: For bodily features, we do say: x's voice, x's legs, x's looks, etc. However, we definitely ***do not say (or write for that matter)***: the legs of Marilyn Monroe. I'm trying to figure out for myself now why that is.  Because if you say: I'd like to have the [legs] of x,  it becomes weird fast. Whereas: I'd like to have the voice of a Jim Morrison is fine.

Comment: I would say its arguable as to whether or not anyone says "I'd like to have the legs of Marilyn Monroe" - but per the OP, the question is linguistically correct.

Comment: People would actually use the possessive: I wish I had Jim Morrison's voice. The same goes for all  envy-inducing body parts. [ahem] I wish I had MM's looks or face or legs.